# Gnuplot: what is the default canvas size for wxt terminal? How can I let pdf terminal output the same look as wxt terminal

Tags: pdf, terminal, gnuplot

What is the default canvas size for wxt terminal? How can I see the current canvas size?

I recently found that the output of wxt and pdf terminal is different in x/y ratio and layout.

I want to find the default wxt size and set a corresponding size for the pdf terminal so that the pdf output will give me the same look as wxt.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default size for the wxt terminal is `640x384` pixels (see the documentation or `help terminal wxt` in the interactive terminal).

Usually you can check the terminal size with `show terminal`, but that doesn't work for interactive terminals:

```
gnuplot> set terminal wxt
Terminal type set to 'wxt'
Options are '0'
gnuplot> show terminal

   terminal type is wxt 0

gnuplot> set terminal pdfcairo
Terminal type set to 'pdfcairo'                                                 
Options are ' transparent fontscale 0.5 size 5.00in, 3.00in '                   
gnuplot> show terminal                                                          

   terminal type is pdfcairo  transparent fontscale 0.5 size 5.00in, 3.00in
```

You can set the size of the wxt terminal with the `size` terminal parameter:

```
set terminal wxt size 1000,600
```

In that case a `show terminal` gives you the canvas size, but that doesn't respect manual changes of the interactive window.

Matching the pdfcairo and wxt terminal is a bit difficult, because the wxt terminal shows a bitmapped image, whereas the pdf is a vector image, which doesn't know a resolution.

To match the pngcairo and the wxt terminal, you must set the same size and for the wxt terminal a `fontscale 1.2`:

```
set terminal wxt size 640,480 fontscale 1.2
test
set terminal pngcairo
set output 'test.png'
test
```

That should result in the same images. To match the wxt and the pdfcairo terminal you must also adjust `size` and `fontscale`. So, I recommend you to get some good settings for your pdf output (possibly adapted to the text width of your paper/thesis/presentation) and then change the `fontscale` and `size` of the wxt terminal to get a similar output.

BTW: The qt terminal of the upcoming 5.0 release has an 'Export to PDF/SVG/PNG' menu, which makes that quite easy.

Comment: Yes. When I first heard QT terminal's new feature from you. I can not be more excited!! I just wish this kinds of export can be done through code as well as I have to plot loads of figures and can not press an export button for each figure. I am a Java programmer and not familiar with how to build Gnuplot. I have to rely on binary releases (the latest version is 4.6.5....) So even if 5.0 is released, a binary build still seems far away. That make me really sad....

Comment: If you're using Windows, you can at least check out an alpha version of 5.0: http://www.gnuplot.info/development/binaries/. I don't know if this export feature will be available from the script code. BTW: Why do you need to match the interactive window and the file output so close together? Usually, I optimized my script for a single data and the single terminal I need for the final result. Afterwards I run the script to generate all other files.

Comment: I feel wxt terminal is more convenient to inspect the figures. These figures can pop out in turns, zoom in and out, etc. After examining & adjusted all figures in wxt, I will then turn an option in my java code to output all these figures in pdf. PDF is my final output, but it is not as convenient as wxt I feel.